# count character occurrences in a string in Java

Tags: java, count, output

I'm trying to get this to print how many letter "a" there are.
It keeps giving me 0...any help?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File myfile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(myfile);
        String word = in.nextLine();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("# of chars: " + counter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("A reading error occured");
    }
}
```

Comment: Print `word`, what do you get?

Comment: Did you try to print `word` before the loop ?

Comment: You are only checking the first line. Does the first line in the file even have a 'a' ?

Comment: @arshajii I get 1604 but that's not right because when I do "b" I get 1604 as well.

Comment: @user2856344 What is 1604 ? the count or the value of word ?

Comment: @Adarsh any advice for making it check all the lines?

Comment: @Adarsh when I print word it gives me 1604

Comment: Maybe you should look at your file then. `1604` doesn't have any `'a'`s nor `'b'`s.

Comment: @ZouZou it gives me 1604 when i do it before the loop as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File myfile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
try {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(myfile);

    int counter = 0;
while(in.hasNextLine()){
 String word = in.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

    System.out.println("# of chars: " + counter);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("A reading error occured");
}
}
```

Comment: how do I make it count the letter a and also the letter b?

Comment: Declare a new counter. And inside the while for loop after the first if, create a new if to check for b, and increment the counter for 'b' . Just like you did for 'a'

Comment: okay thanks and also how to make it so it counts both 'A' and 'a'? Do i have to make a separate if or is there an easier way?

Comment: Both 'A and a' or 'A or a'

Comment: I want it to count both 'A' and 'a' so it's case insensitive because right now it's only counting 'a'.

Comment: convert the word to lower case, so it will count both A and a.

Comment: I've been messing with the code and cant find where to put word toLowerCase()

Comment: word.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'a'

Comment: One more thing that I'm trying to figure out as well...how would you implement the code so that it counts 'y' only when it's a vowel

Comment: it's sometimes a vowel and sometimes not but i need it to count y if it's at the end of a word.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say. What is y ? is it a variable ?

Comment: The letter 'y'. I want the program to count the letter 'y' when it's the last letter of the word.

Comment: inside the for loop, split the line into words and then check the last letter of the word. Check online on how to split a line into words.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler (one line) way of counting occurrences of a char is:

```
int count = word.replaceAll("[^a]", "").length();
```

This replaces every character that's not an "a" with a blank - effectively deleting it - leaving you with a string containing just the "a" characters of the original string, then you get the length of that.

Comment: beautiful; maybe not as resource-efficient as possible, but certainly quick to write.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond any issues reading the file, also try using the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) countMatches. It's already in the common lang, mind as well use that instead.

For example

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(word, "a");
```